# Why does the Python regex ".*PATTERN*" match "XXPATTERXX"?

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I want to find `"PATTERN"` in a string, where `"PATTERN"` could be anywhere in the string. My first try was `*PATTERN*`, but this generates an error saying that there is "nothing to repeat", which I can accept so I tried `.*PATTERN*`. This regex does however not give the expected result, see below

```
import re
p = re.compile(".*PATTERN*")
s = "XXPATTERXX"
if p.match(s):
    print s + " match with '.*PATTERN*'"
```

The result is

```
XXPATTERXX match with '.*PATTERN*'
```

Why does `"PATTER"` match?

Note: I know that I could use `.*PATTERN.*` to get the expected result, but I am curious to find out why the asterisk on it self fails to get the results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your pattern matches 0 or more `N` characters at the end, but doesn't say anything about what comes after those `N` characters.

You could add `$` to the pattern to anchor to the end of the input string to disallow the `XX`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.compile(".*PATTERN*$")
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x10029fb90>
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile(".*PATTERN*$")
>>> p.match("XXPATTERXX") is None
True
>>> p.match("XXPATTER") is None
False
>>> p.match("XXPATTER")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1004627e8>
```

You may want to look into the different types of anchor. `\b` may also fit your needs; it matches word boundaries (so between a `\w` and `\W` class character, or between `\W` and `\w`), or you could use negative look-ahead and look-behinds to disallow other characters around your `PATTERN` string.

Comment: I realized that `.*PATTERN` is sufficient in my case.